# Implementing Multichannel ADC conversion and transfer data to PC

Tags: msp430, ti-ccstudio

I have developed a system using the **TI MSP430 G2553** that accomplishes analog to digital conversion of multiple sensors simultaneously.

So here is the question:

Can someone suggest me how to transfer the digital output of the ADC to the PC and store it in say, a text file?

**EDIT**: I am making use of CCS as my IDE for programming the microcontroller. Is there something inherent in CCS which will help me accomplish the task?

Comment: Did you try plugging it in?

Comment: Yes. I was told I need some PC side software like RealTerm to gather the data from uC to PC , and later export it to a text file. However, is there something inherent in Code Composer Studio which will help me accomplish this?

Comment: @Gautham - No. At best, CCS will have something similar to a terminal.

Comment: I see.. any suggestion as how to do it?

Comment: Probably the minimum need to add is the MSP430 / board you're using so we have an idea of what USB / serial ports are available. Using one of those two options would be the usual way.

Comment: I'm using the TI MSP430G2553

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the UART module in the MSP430 to transfer data. Using a USB to serial converter, interface it to the PC. You may use a python script to read the data coming to the PC and store it as a text file.

See this sample project http://eliaselectronics.com/plotting-serial-data-using-gnuplot-and-python/